# Load/save plain PPMs without error checking

Tags: beginner, image, io, lua

I'm learning Lua. I decided to make a simple [plain PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) decoder/encoder without error checks to familiarize myself with the language. I would appreciate any feedback on how could I make the following code simpler, shorter, more elegant and readable.

```
-- Load/save plain PPMs without error checking; img[img.w][img.h].r=img.maxVal
-- sets the red channel of pixel at the top-right corner to the reddest value

local p3 = {}

function p3.load(path)
    local file = io.open(path)
    local data = file:read('a')
    file:close()
    data = data:gsub('#[^\n]*', ' ') -- remove comments
    local w, h, maxVal = data:match('P3'..('%s*(%d+)'):rep(3))
    w, h, maxVal = tonumber(w), tonumber(h), tonumber(maxVal)
    data = data:sub(#data:match('P3'..('%s*%d+'):rep(3)) + 1) -- remove header
    local img = { w = w, h = h, maxVal = maxVal }
    for x = 1, w do
        img[x] = {}
        for y = 1, h do
            img[x][y] = {}
        end
    end
    local channels = { 'r', 'g', 'b' }
    local startIndex, endIndex = 1, 1
    for y = h, 1, -1 do
        for x = 1, w do
            for _, ch in ipairs(channels) do
                startIndex, endIndex = data:find('%d+', startIndex)
                img[x][y][ch] = tonumber(data:sub(startIndex, endIndex))
                startIndex = endIndex + 1
            end
        end
    end
    return img
end

function p3.save(img, path)
    local file = io.open(path, 'w')
    file:write('P3\n', img.w, ' ', img.h, '\n', img.maxVal, '\n')
    for y = img.h, 1, -1 do
        for x = 1, img.w do
            file:write(img[x][y].r, ' ', img[x][y].g, ' ', img[x][y].b, '\n')
        end
    end
    file:close()
end

return p3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems readable enough for me. When you're working with a standardized data there is no room for ingenuity, just a mechanical work that needs to be done correctly.

Maybe it is only this snippet `'P3'..('%s*(%d+)'):rep(3)`, that makes you thin for a while, whether there will be three `'P3'`s in result.

Comment: You're right! `'P3%s*(%d+)%s*(%d+)%s*(%d+)'` is clearer than `'P3'..('%s*(%d+)'):rep(3)`. I should also change `'P3'..('%s*%d+'):rep(3)` to `'P3%s*%d+%s*%d+%s*%d+'` for consistency. Thank you for your feedback!